# Duvida sobre Socket php

Tags: php, socket

Estou começando a estudar sobre Sockets, e peguei como base o código do seguinte video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqDdHjJBZVw

A dúvida é:
Porque só funciona quando chamado através do cls no CMD?
Quando eu inicio o serviço do apache no Xampp, e tento executar os server pelo navegador, o mesmo não funciona.

Ja fiz o comando netstat -a, -an para pegar uma porta que não esta sendo usada.

Estou usando os seguintes códigos:
Cliente:

```
<?php
echo "\n Type your username:  ";
$user = trim(fgets(STDIN));
if(strlen($user) <= 2) { exit; }
else {
while(1)
{   
    echo "\n Please say something or enter 'q' to quit:  ";
    $ticker = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    if($ticker=='q') { exit; }

    $socket= socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
    if($socket===false)
    {
        echo "Socket creation failed!";
    }
    $result = socket_connect($socket,"127.0.0.1",1234);
    if($result===false)
    {
        echo "Socket connection failed!";
    }
        else { 
        socket_write($socket,"$user says --> $ticker",1024);
         }
    }
}
?>
```

Servidor:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
set_time_limit(0);
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 1234;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create
socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to
socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket) or die("Could not set up socket
listener\n");
echo "Waiting for connections... \n";
while(1)
{
    $spawn[++$i] = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming
    connection\n");
    echo "_______________________________________________________\n";
    $input = socket_read($spawn[$i],1024);
    $client = $input;

    echo $client ."\n";

    socket_close($spawn[$i]);
    echo "_______________________________________________________\n";
}
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Ps: Mesmo através do CMD, se eu inicio o apache no Xampp ele não funciona.

Se alguem puder mandar um código client/server só para eu estudar, como funciona no navegador, me ajudaria muito.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você deve testar se a extenxão está compilada antes de utilizar os sockets:

```
if (!extension_loaded('sockets')) {
    die('Sockets não disponível.');
}
```

Provavelmente está presente somente na versão CLI.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste e retornou true, a extensão esta carregada. 
Fiz um Debug, e o problema ocorre no metodo socket_bind.

Comment: Certo, verifica e posta aqui o valor de socket_last_error()

Comment: O erro ocorre na linha do metodo socket_bind, coloquei o socket_last_error() depois do die, o resultado foi esse:
Could not bind to socket - socket last error = 10048

Comment: Parece que esta em uso, tente utilizar o socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) antes do bind. Verifique tambem a versao string da mensagem com socket_strerror(socket_last_error()).. deve ser mais elucidativo a respeito do erro que esta ocorrendo.

Comment: Sem usar o socket_set_option, ocorreu a seguinte msg: 
Could not bind to socket - Normalmente � permitida apenas uma utiliza��o de cada endere�o de soquete (protocolo/endere�o de rede/porta).

Comment: Colocando o socket_set_option, conforme vc pediu. A mensagem foi essa:
Could not bind to socket - Foi feita uma tentativa de acesso a um soquete de uma maneira que � proibida pelas permiss�es de acesso.

Comment: Pelo que estou entendendo, antes do arquivo server.php conseguir acessar a porta, o apache do xamp acessa a porta primeiro, dai ocorre o conflito.

Comment: Ao que parece o usuario que está rodando no servidor web nao tem permissao suficiente para isso, o que me faz questionar do por que criar um servidor para receber conexões dentro de uma pagina. Faz mais sentido na console mesmo. Seria legal exclarecer esse proposito na questao.

Comment: Na verdade eu só queria saber por que não funciona quando o apache ta ligado. Acho que o socket não funciona com servidor web ligado, pois o servidor web acessa a porta antes do socket, acho que é isso.

Comment: Parece conflito na porta, bota o servidor socket em outra porta que deve resolver.